# Telerik Reporting issue when loading report

Tags: asp.net, telerik-reporting

Anybody have idea about this? I am using telerik reporting and when i click report viewer it is happening. Recently i upgraded telerik.

No exception is showing in the code so that am very much confusing!

[image]

Can anyone please help me for solving this?

Comment: Does the error go away if you rollback the upgrade to its  previous version? If you google the error message it indicates, that your report viewer might be outdated and you need to update some assembly versions

Comment: I checked and it seems working..thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method not found: Telerik.Reporting.IReportDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49321300/method-not-found-telerik-reporting-ireportdocument)